# Asus Zenbook UM433D Ubuntu 19.04 no sound

Tags: sound, asus

This is my first post, so please forgive me if I break any rules here.
I just successfully installed Ubuntu 19.04 onto my recently purchased Asus Zenbook model UM433D. Everything is working wonderfully, except that when I try to listen to audio, such as on YouTube videos, at first there is an initial short fluttering burst of sound and then it goes silent.
I am aware users of 18.04 with Asus problems have reported similar problems, but I am unaware of the solution for my version of Ubuntu.
Thank you for your help

Here is the output from Ubuntu 19.10 when I run the command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`

```
03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller [1002:15de]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller [1002:15de]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
03:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2]
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x
03:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1043:1b71]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: Since it was a clean install; Ubuntu 19.04 or the 2019-April release of Ubuntu, reaches EOL very soon (supported till 18-Jan-2020) so I'd start fresh by installing Ubuntu 19.10.  Standard releases like 19.04/19.10 have 9 months of supported life; the format of release is *year.month* so EOL is easy to calculate.  I'd suggest installing 19.10 as why spend effort on something that'll be gone in a month.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and help. However, I am in Ubuntu 19.10 and yet I am still unable to hear sound on my laptop, except for in the fluttering bursts I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Asus Zenbook UX392FN and a clean installation of Ubuntu 19.10, but it is solved now:

1. Open the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file with `sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
2. Add the following line to the end of the file: `options snd-hda-intel model=auto`
3. Restart the system.

My solution is based on information from another [webpage](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html). The parameter `model=generic` didn't work for me.

As your sound system may use same hardware, please test if it solves your problem too.