# No sound on Ubuntu 20.04/21.10 on Asus ZenBook UM433D

Tags: sound, asus

I've been trying to get sound to play. I can see on the sound app's equaliser that sound is actually being played, but nothing is audible through the speakers or headphone port.

I have checked ALSAMixer and have found nothing muted; everything was set to max volume.
I have attempted the fix listed here: [Asus Zenbook UM433D Ubuntu 19.04 no sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196947/asus-zenbook-um433d-ubuntu-19-04-no-sound) which unfortunately did nothing.

Googling, I have found suggestions that it may actually be a kernel problem, but I am a desktop user; I have no idea how to forcibly update the kernel as the terminal is mostly foreign ground to me. I have also attempted to use pavucontrol to fix the issue, but I have had no luck.

EDIT: I attempted the fix mentioned below, of adding options snd-hda-intel model=auto to alsa-base.conf to the file. No change, still no sound.

Comment: Please confirm: Did you append `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` to `alsa-base.conf`, **saved** and rebooted and it didn't work?

Comment: Correct, it resulted in no change. Sound being played, but nothing being heard.